# Never seen this notation before: $\int (y-f(x))^2 Pr(dx,dy) $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, statistics, notation

I have never seen an integral like this:

$$\int (y-f(x))^2 Pr(dx,dy) $$

What is that? More precisely what is $Pr(dx,dy)$? And how is that integral defined? I found it in Elements of Statistical Learning, By T. Hastie, et. al.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$Pr(dx,dy)$ is the joint distribution. For example, if the density of the joint distribution is $g(x,y)$ , then
$$
\int (y-f(x))^2 Pr(dx,dy)=\int\int (y-f(x))^2 g(x,y)\,dx\,dy,
$$
over your region of integration.

Comment: Oh, I see. Would you please rewrite $Pr(X,Y) = Pr(Y|X)Pr(X)$? I want to make sure that I have understood it correctly. (Is Pr(X) the marginal distribution on X?)

Comment: As usual: $$\int (y-f(x))^2 Pr(dx,dy)=\int\left[\int (y-f(x))^2 \frac{g(x,y)}{g(x)}\,dy\right] g(x)\,dx,$$where $g(x)$ is the marginal density.